# Resize the background image on Browser's resize

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I'm using EaselJs to build my game and I would like to catch the onresize event of the browser in order to resize the stage and all images it contains.

I've tried this code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);

init() {
   createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', handleTick);
   resize();
}

function handleTick(event) {
  stage.update();
}

function resize() {
  stage.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

But it didn't really work...Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you resize the canvas contents with JavaScript, then you are adding more pixels to the canvas element. The contents will not resize to fit.

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
```

If you resize with CSS, then you are transforming the element, so it has the same number of pixels, but is stretched.

```
canvas.style.width = window.innerWith;
```

If you want to scale the contents to fit on more pixels, you need to scale the stage, or better, put your contents inside a container and scale that.

Here is a quick sample I made to answer a similar question, which should get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/4yy08pax/

Comment: Your example and explanation really helped me!! thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know canvas should maintain their ratio automatically if you set their width using relative units (e.g.  100 %). Obviously children elements should be relative as well to achieve a fluid layout.

If you want to use javascript to obtain the same result you should use the correct events listener

```
window.onresize
```

Comment: I have no problem catching the 'onresize' browser event, when I catch the event and set new width and height to the stage - nothing really happens...

Comment: Try checking your developer tools console, do you see any errors? Does stage.canvas returns undefined?

Comment: Nope, no errors in console.
If I got it right, the resize function gives the canvas a new width and height and update the stage which should automatically resize all elements on stage, is that correct?

Comment: by the way, why do we need the tick event? we could have put stage.update() in the resize method, no?